# Ограничить одновременные запросы к серверу в ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть следующий код, который используется в расширение chrome:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://sitename.com",
dataType: 'json',
async: false,
success: function(data) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
```

Который делает одновременные запросы к методу api, всего их 24. 
Но, api дает только 8 запросов в секунду. 
Как можно заставить запросы отправляться к примеру с задержкой 130мс?

Answer (score 1):

Так как `async: false`, то запросы не одновременные. Они по очереди.

```
$a = ["url1", "url2", ... "url24"];
$.each($a, function(k, v){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: v
        });
    }, k * 125);
});
```

125 - это 1/8 секунды; k - индекс массива, но лучше переменную с инкрементом завести

Comment: Но вопрос был о том как ограничить их количество за секунду . У $.ajax наверное не такой опции, и придется делать самому задерживающую прослойку, через которую вызывать $.ajax.

Comment: Добавил. Надеюсь, есть возможность так сделать.